# Использование SSD на хостинге

Tags: ssd, hdd, хостинг

Современные хостеры часто в качестве дополнительной опции предлагают SSD как дополнение к HDD. Цены на HDD обычно на порядок (более чем в десять раз) больше чем цены на SSD (цена из расчета 1 Гб в месяц).

Вопрос: в чем прелесть SSD при такой разнице в цене? Что дает использование SSD и как обычно это SSD используется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Среди преимуществ использования SSD накопителей отмечаются в первую очередь:

- отсутствие шума от движущихся частей и охлаждающих вентиляторов
- высокая механическая стойкость
- широкий диапазон рабочих температур
- малый размер и вес
- более высокая скорость запуска
- высокая скорость работы с данными
- малое время считывания информации
- низкая потребляемая энергия

Визуальные [отличия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Disassembled_HDD_and_SSD.JPG) HDD от SSD